# How to decompress stream deflated with java.util.zip.Deflater in .NET?

Tags: java, .net, compression, zlib, deflate

I have a dump after `java.util.zip.Deflater` (can confirm it's valid because Java's `Inflater` opens it fine) and need to open it in .NET:

```
byte[] content = ReadSample(sampleName);
var input = new MemoryStream(content);
var output = new MemoryStream();

using (var z = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
        z.CopyTo(output);
```

This throws

> System.IO.InvalidDataException : Block length does not match with its
>   complement.

Tried `Ionic.Zlib.DeflateStream` - similar exception. How can i do that?

The dump starts with 97 86 E8 92 47 3D 40 EA (if that matters).

**Update:** Unfortunately, i have no control over Java party as the system is in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no control over the Java output, how about integrating some J# in your .NET app in order to use `java.util.zip.Inflater` directly? See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164129.aspx).

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522778/java-util-zip-deflater-equivalent-in-c-sharp) might also be helpful, particularly the suggestion of [#zipLib](http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/).

Answer (score 1):

To resolve platform dependent copression and decompression use

**Approach-1**

In .NET you can use [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)

In Java use *java.util.zip.GZIPOutPutStream*

**Approach-2**

You can also use 7-zip. There is an SDK for both c# and Java.

Comment: I had luck using Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream for compression in c# and then GZIPInputStream in Java for decompression. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Deflater and Inflater are standard formats and I would be surprised if it were the same in Java and C#.

I would suggest you use a standard format such as GZIP which should be the same across platforms.

Comment: -1 The whole point of Deflater/Inflater (in Java or C#) is to provide high level API for the zlib library which also implements GZIP.